# What is the difference between $\lim{(a_n)} = a$ and $(a_n) \to a$

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on some homework for analysis and in class we give the algebraic limit theorems, which I would like to take advantage of in my homework.  Now on a homework problem I am given "Let $a_n \to 0$" is this same same as $\lim{a_n} = 0$?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: Yes, it is the same.

Comment: For clarity, I was taught to draw $\infty$ under the arrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are the same thing. Sometimes the former works better from a writing standpoint, which I would read as "Let $a_n$ tend towards 0...", which to me sounds better than "Let the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = {0}$".

Comment: The book we are using made the leap from one to the other while never really defining the arrow notation.  I know it makes sense in context that that is what is happening, however I hate making assumptions.

Comment: That's a good attitude to have, and it's something that we as writers should be cautious about sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

There is sometimes a slight difference, albeit the two are pretty much equivalent most of the time.

Namely, when you write $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq a$, you implicitly assume that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ converges, *but not* to $a$; while when you write $a_n\operatorname*{\nrightarrow}_{n\to\infty} a$, the sequence might either (i) diverge or (ii) converge to a value $b\neq a$.